# sum of constant percentage increase

Tags: summation

I don't remember the formula for adding up (n) numbers that are constantly increasing at a certain percentage.
Example if n=3, that means adding up 3 years:
year 1 = 100
year 2 = 100 * 1.03 = 103
year 3 = 100 * 1.03 * 1.03 = 106.09
total = 309.09

Answer (score 1):

This is the sum of a geometric progression:

$$a + ar +ar^2+\dots+ar^n=a{r^{n+1}-1\over r-1}$$

In your example, $a=100, r=1.03, n=2$

Comment: Thanks. I tried the formula but I find that it should be r^n and not r^(n-1).

Comment: @jackie Actually, it should be $r^{n+1}.$  Just a typo, sorry.